# rails 3.1 active record insert or update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, insert

I'm new to rails.

Is there an easy way in active record to pass it a hash of data and if the record exists, update it, and if it doesn't, create it?

```
data = {}
data["my_id"] = 356345
data["description"] = "test123"

w = Descriptions.new(data)
```

Ideally if I ran the above it would only ever have 1 record, not multiple records each time I ran it.

Comment: This is like SQL update or insert.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you ware wanting the "my_id" bit to be unique you can run

```
Descriptions.find_or_create_by_my_id(data["my_id"]).update_attributes(data)
```

Comment: `pablo` is new to rails.and you are telling him to use patch way!

Comment: Don't see what should be wrong here. my_id is not the primary key. So it's totally fine.

Comment: Hi I liked your answer as well but I'm a newbe so I'm a little lost here, how do I use this into a mass insert? Should I create another question?

Comment: Hey friend, I hope you found your answer. But for completion sake, the find_or_create method finds the object, and the update attributes will do an update on the object. The data variable is supposed to contain all attributes you want to insert (and save) into your object. Does that help?

Comment: You could use `find_or_initialize` instead. This answer works, but it will save twice (1. create, 2. update) for new records.

Comment: Did not know there was a find_or_initialize Thats awesome!

Answer (score 0):

An ActiveRecord object in Rails retains its identity in the ID parameter. If the ID is set, Rails will know to update the record in the database with that ID.

`save` is, in fact, the primary way to create, update, or in any way save an object to the database. Other methods like `update_attributes` are just sugar that use `save` at their core.

Yes,There are many good things you will get `ModelName.find_or_create_by_name("Summer")`

But If you pass Id in `save` method that will be update and if id is not passed it will `create` data.

Always, Primary Key in Rails should be "id" but you used "my_id" that may also be the problem.