# How to properly insert or update record in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, upsert

Apparently, I saw [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373540/rails-3-1-active-record-insert-or-update) [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599113/activerecord-update-a-record-if-exists-else-create) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988091/rails-3-2-8-insert-or-update-based-on-condition) with answers like: "Use `find_or_create_by`/`initialize_by(<cols>)`."

And the question is: "Is it just me, or those answers are a little bit 'broken'?" If one asks for insert or update, it usually means that the records are supposed to be unique: no two records with matching `<cols>` should exist. Following those answers one will either eventually get duplicate rows in database, or will occasionally have exceptions (if uniqueness is enforced with unique index).

Why nobody suggests this way?

```
begin
  Counter.create(name: '...', value: 1)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  Counter.where(name: '...').update_all('value = value + 1')
end
```

So which is it? Should I go with `find_or_create_by`/`initialize_by`? Or should I rely on db's unique index? On a side note, I can't think of any case where one wants to do insert or update *and* okay with having duplicate rows.

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question?

Comment: Isn't this satisfied by simply using good validations?  Remember that the concept behind rails is convention over configuration.  Why complicate something if it's not necessary to do so?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Because validations are subject to race conditions, that's why certain logic must go in the database.

Comment: @HolgerJust Well, sort of. I expect somebody to prove me wrong. Not happening yet. Or right. So not really rhetorical.

Answer (score -1):

Because `begin...rescue` should not be used for that.

`begin...rescue` is for when an error condition occurs.

Here is an example from [Ruby Learning](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html).

```
def inverse(x)  
  raise ArgumentError, 'Argument is not numeric' unless x.is_a? Numeric  
  1.0 / x  
end
```

Your example of a duplicate record isn't really an "error", because it can happen whenever duplicate data is submitted.

`find_or_create_by` elegantly handles both cases, without the notion of an "error condition".

Comment: But a violation of a unique constraint in the database *is* an error. Just because something is an error at one level doesn't mean it has to be an error at all levels. BTW, `find_or_create_by` is just `find_by(...) || create(...)` so it is still subject to race conditions, The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) even recommends wrapping it in an exception handler if uniqueness is required.